# iOS 6 Autolayout not working which is working fine in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, autolayout

As I don't know more about auto layout. So this is my first application in which I'm using auto layout. This may be duplicate but I need your help to resolve it.

My question is I have a view in which on button click event I'm showing a drop down with 2 `UITextFields` in it and 1 `UIButton`, which is working fine in iOS 7. But when I tried same with iOS 6, first time subviews of drop down view like 1 button and 2 `UITextFields` position and totally messed and  when I close drop down and tried to reopen it showing proper drop down view same as of iOS 7.

[image: This is the first time when I push the view showing blank]

[image: This is when I close the drop down view and reopen it]

Code to show drop down view is

```
      - (IBAction)show:(id)sender 
        {
          self.dropDownContainerView.hidden=NO;
          addMemberPopup = [[DropDownPopup alloc] initWithContentView:self.dropDownContainerView];
          addMemberPopup.delegate = self;
          addMemberPopup.title = @"Add Member";
          [addMemberPopup showInView:self.view animated:YES];
        }

    - (BOOL) showInView:(UIView *)parentView animated:(BOOL)animated
     {
        self.frame = parentView.bounds;

       CGRect internalViewFrame = CGRectInset(self.contentView.bounds, -MARGIN, -(int)(MARGIN * 1 + HEADERHEIGHT / 2));
       internalViewFrame.size.height -= 2;
       internalViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, -MARGIN);
       self.internalMainView.frame = internalViewFrame;

       CGRect internalMainViewFrame = CGRectOffset(internalViewFrame, (int)(self.frame.size.width - self.internalMainView.frame.size.width) / 2, 0);
       self.internalMainView.frame = internalMainViewFrame;

       [parentView addSubview:self];

      if (animated)
       {
           int actualHeight = self.internalMainView.frame.size.height;
           CGRect internalMainViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.internalMainView.frame.origin.x,                self.internalMainView.frame.origin.y, self.internalMainView.frame.size.width, 0);
           self.internalMainView.frame = internalMainViewFrame;

          CGFloat animationDuration = ANIMATIONDURATION;
          CGRect finalInternalMainViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.internalMainView.frame.origin.x, self.internalMainView.frame.origin.y, self.internalMainView.frame.size.width, actualHeight);

          [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations: ^(void) {
          self.internalMainView.frame = finalInternalMainViewFrame;
         }

        ];
       }    

return YES;
```

}

Please help me to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Autolayout, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @jrturton: I don't know why this is not showing on first launch but when I reopen it it works fine......

Comment: @jrturton: Can you just let me know possible solution for the same?

Comment: @FahimParkar I have remove auto layout and works ....means it was problem with auto layout?

Comment: @Hrishikesh : Autolayout works differently in iOS 6 and iOS7. I would say use auto-layout only when you know it perfectly...  I never use auto-layout as its makes me crazy in adjusting the positions...

Comment: @FahimParkar Even I have face same problem in iOS 6 and iOS 7.... don't know how to resolve such issue now... if I remove auto layout then in that case I need to update each view in it which is very hectic task to do...

Comment: @Hrishikesh : Add constraint then... I would say take some time and keep removing the Auto-layout... with auto-layout you will spend 2 hrs, but same work can be done in 30 mins without auto-layout.